# Compile kernel to DLL and use it

Tags: pointers, dll, cuda

I managed to make whole thing with function pointers work and now I want to dynamically load such a kernel.
My code:

cuh:

```
ifndef customkernel_cuh
define customkernel_cuh

extern "C" pfunctionWhere __declspec(dllexport) getHostPointer();

endif
```

cu:

```
__device__
    bool myWhere2(PapayaColumnValue *values)
{
    return ((int)values[1]) == 1 || ((int)values[1]) == 3;
}
__device__ pfunctionWhere pMyWhere2 = myWhere2;

pfunctionWhere __declspec(dllexport) getHostPointer()
{
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    pfunctionWhere h_pMyWhere2;
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_pMyWhere2, pMyWhere2, sizeof(pfunctionWhere));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return h_pMyWhere2;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("xxx.dll");
    if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {
        std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
    }
    dll_func dll_getHostPointer = (dll_func)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "getHostPointer");
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 
    if (!dll_getHostPointer) {
        std::cout << "could not locate the function" << std::endl;
    }
    pfunctionWhere h_pMyWhere2 = (*dll_getHostPointer)();
```

And if I debug into dll `cudaStatus = cudaSuccess`, but pointer to function is null and it is returned from dll invocation. My question is: is it possible to write kernel functions in DLL and then get pointer to such kernels and pass it to main program? I need it to be able to change the kernel while main program is working.

Answer (score 1):

You could compile your kernel code to PTX and run it using CUDA driver API, see [CUDA C Programming Guide / Driver Api / Module](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#module).

If you invoke `nvcc` with `-ptx` option instead of `--compile`, it will generate ptx files. It is not linked with your exe program, and you can change ptx files at any time.

Comment: I am trying to load some code that can be compiled after compiling main program and then it could be changed and reload. Would it be possible with PTX?

Comment: Yes, you compiele ptx files separately from cpu program.

Answer (score 0):

The whole code doesn't make sense.

First, you are not checking the `cudaStatus`.

Second you are copying from constant memory, but why? surely you didn't update the constant memory in your kernel. You are probably looking for `cudaMemcpy` not `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`

Have a Google on "Pinned Memory", it might be useful in your case.

Comment: this is based on first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644261/cuda-function-pointers

I am checking cudaStatus via debugger. Copying from constant memory via cudaMemcpyFromSymbol is a way for passing pointer to device function to kernel. You have it in a link above