# CUDA: How to return a device lambda from a host function

Tags: c++, lambda, cuda

I have a virtual function which returns a different lambda depending on the derived class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::function<float()> foo(void) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    std::function<float()> foo(void) {
        return [] __device__ (void) {
            return 1.0f;
        };
    }
};
```

Then I want to pass this lambda to a CUDA kernel and call it from the device. In other words, I want to do this:

```
template<typename Func>
__global__ void kernel(Func f) {
    f();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Base* obj = new Derived;
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(obj->foo());
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

Tha above give an error like this: `calling a __host__ function("std::function<float ()> ::operator ()") from a __global__ function("kernel< ::std::function<float ()> > ") is not allowed`

As you can see, I declare my lambda as `__device__`, but the `foo()` method stores it in a `std::function` in order to return it. As a result, what is passed to the `kernel()` is a host address and of course it does not work. I guess that is my problem, right? So my questions are:

- Is it somehow possible to create a `__device__ std::function` and return that from the `foo()` method?
- If this is not possible, is there any other way to dynamically select a lambda and pass it to the CUDA kernel? Hard-coding multiple calls to `kernel()` with all the possible lambdas is not an option.

So far, from the quick research I did, CUDA does not have/support the necessary syntax required to make a function return a device lambda. I just hope I am wrong. :) Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is a question of syntax. `std::function` isn't supported on the device, which is the source of the compile error, from what I can see

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381254/cuda-c11-array-of-lambdas-function-by-index-not-working/41399827#41399827).  I think it is certainly possible to use a `__device__` lambda as a kernel parameter/argument, but you are probably using `std::function` because you want to "genericize" it - you don't like the fact that [every lambda has a unique type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477310/why-cant-i-create-a-vector-of-lambda-in-c11).  You won't be able to use `std::function` to work around that, I don't think.  It might be easier to use functors for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before actually answering, I have to wonder whether your question isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That is, I am by default skeptical that people have a good excuse for executing code through lambdas/function pointers on the device.

But I won't evade your question like that...

> Is it somehow possible to create a `__device__ std::function` and return that from the foo() method?

Short answer: No, try something else.

Longer answer: If you want to implement a large chunk of the standard library on the device side, then maybe you could have a device-side `std::function`-like class. But I'm not sure that's even possible (quite possibly not), and anyway - it's beyond the capabilities of everyone except *very* seasoned library developers. So, do something else.

> If this is not possible, is there any other way to dynamically select a lambda and pass it to the CUDA kernel? Hard-coding multiple calls to kernel() with all the possible lambdas is not an option.

First, remember that lambdas are essentially anonymous classes - and thus, if they don't capture anything, they're reducible to function pointers since the anonymous classes have no data, just an `operator()`.

So if the lambdas have the same signature and no capture, you [can cast them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28746827/1593077) into a (non-member-)function pointer and pass those to the function; and this definitely works, see [this simple example](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/457094/cuda-programming-and-performance/how-can-i-use-__device__-function-pointer-in-cuda-/post/3247854/#3247854) on nVIDIA's forums.

Another possibility is using run-time mapping from type id's or other such keys into instances of these types, or rather, to constructors. That is, using a *factory*. But I don't want to get into the details of that to not make this answer longer than it already is; and it's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think you can achieve what you want using virtual functions that return device lambdas, you can achieve something similar by passing a static device member function as the template parameter to your kernel. An example is provided below. Note that the classes in this example could also be structs if you prefer.

```
#include <iostream>

// Operation: Element-wise logarithm
class OpLog {
    public:
    __device__ static void foo(int tid, float * x) {
        x[tid] = logf(x[tid]);
    };
};

// Operation: Element-wise exponential
class OpExp {
    public:
    __device__ static void foo(int tid, float * x) {
        x[tid] = expf(x[tid]);
    }
};

// Generic kernel
template < class Op >
__global__ void my_kernel(float * x) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    Op::foo(tid,x);
}

// Driver
int main() {

    using namespace std;

    // length of vector
    int len = 10;

    // generate data
    float * h_x = new float[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        h_x[i] = rand()/float(RAND_MAX);
    }

    // inspect data
    cout << "h_x = [";
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        cout << h_x[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;

    // copy onto GPU
    float * d_x;
    cudaMalloc(&d_x, len*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(d_x, h_x, len*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Take the element-wise logarithm
    my_kernel<OpLog><<<1,len>>>(d_x);

    // get result
    cudaMemcpy(h_x, d_x, len*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout << "h_x = [";
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        cout << h_x[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;

    // Take the element-wise exponential
    my_kernel<OpExp><<<1,len>>>(d_x);

    // get result
    cudaMemcpy(h_x, d_x, len*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout << "h_x = [";
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        cout << h_x[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;


}
```